# SQL Injection cshtml

Tags: c#, sql, razor, code-injection

So I've asked a few questions on here and been roasted for using SQL injection vulnurable code, even though the site won't be online I've been advised to fix it anyway which I'm now trying to do.

So I did a testpage to test it out, with this following code.

```
var date = "2017-01-26";

var testQuery = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE date = @0";
db.Execute(testQuery, date);
```

So far, just running this page it gives me no error, but probably around 99% of the time I select something from the database I use a `foreach` to show my data.

```
foreach (var c in db.Query(testQuery))
{
    <a>@c.kg</a>
}
```

And by adding a foreach like this it gives me an error:

`A parameter is missing. [ Parameter ordinal = 1 ]`

What am I doing wrong? And is this even SQL injection secure otherwise?
PS. This isn't a MVC type project.

Comment: you need to add parameter value to your query

Comment: This is logic. I suggest that you place it in your `Controller` instead, and send it as a model into your view. But that's not related to your problem. It's just a side-note.

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev- obviously `db.Execute` do it

Comment: What is the type of  `db`?

Comment: Also, you can clearly see the difference in these: in the first one you provide `date` to `Execute()`, in the second one you don't.

Comment: [Regarding SQL-Injection in general](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen SQL server compact I believe(.sdf in webmatrix). Oh, didn't know I had to do that, seems like it would be a lot of variables there if you have lots of conditions in the query?

Comment: Yes, of course you need to provide a value for each parameter you use. How else would it have a value? :)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen but then, adding `db.Query(testQuery, date)`, is this now considered a safe sql injection preventing thing? Also, I dont really understand all of these things, if things I do work I will remember it, not necessarily understand how all of it works, hehe

Comment: @smoksnes I guess you didn't get through the whole text, but this isn't a MVC project, I would like to learn about that in the future though.

Answer (score 1):

If your db is EF context, default parameter name is `p0` , ie query should be

```
var testQuery = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE date = @p0";
foreach (var c in db.Query(testQuery, date)) ...
```

alternatively provide `SqlParameter` as a second parameter instead of plain value

```
db.Query("... = @p", new SqlParameter('p', date))
```